# adobe connect with php

Tags: php, adobe, adobe-connect

I am very new to adobe connect. I want to integrate single sign on with adobe connect and php.
If customer is logging in through our website then he must logged in to the adobe connect and got access to the meetings. 
I have asked this several other places but got no response. Please give some solutions.

In fact I am successful in some extent. I am able to call this:

https://example.com/api/xml?action=principal-update&first-name=jazz&lastname=doe&login=jazz99@doe.com&password=hello&type=user&send-email=true&haschildren=0&email=jazz99@doe.com

after that I have been redirected to adobe connect api page and got response like this:

jammdoe@example.com
    jammdoe@example.com
    jamm doe

Now, I want that if status code is Ok, then either return back to our site or redirect to adobe connect with logged in.

Comment: Can you post the solution here? It will be very helpful for others.

Comment: I also tried a lot , no success yet..! can any one help. I able to create Login , and Create Meeting via PHP / Curl but now wanted to fetch full User list in XML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing this lib https://github.com/brunogasparetto/AdobeConnectClient to use the Adobe Connect 9 API.

With the lib you can create the usar with principalCreate method (https://github.com/brunogasparetto/AdobeConnectClient/blob/master/examples/principalCreate.php) and when he log in you can use the login and password to log in the Adobe Connect.

For now many actions are missing.